# Use Exchange Property in Camel DSL "to"

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to set a property on a Camel Exchange and then use this property when saving the file.  In my camel dsl I have the following:

```
.process(processorToSetExhangeProperty)  // sets the property <uid> on the exchange
.to("file:/tmp?fileName=file-" + property("uid") + ".xml")
```

The file is being saved as:

```
"file-property{uid}.xml" though
```

My processor is as follows:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    exchange.setProperty("uid", uuid.toString());
    exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());
}
```

Any thoughts on what may be going wrong or how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `to` in the Camel is not interpreted at runtime.

You should use recipientList if you want to construct your URI dynamically. 
See https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED**
New answer accepted above instead of this previous one:

---

The answer is [was]:

.to("file:/tmp?fileName=file-${property.uid}") + ".xml")

This simple expression pulls in the exchange property.  For a complete list of what you can pull in, see the [Simple Expression Language Reference](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)

Comment: This is partially false: as V.Goldin said, the `to()` component is evaluated during the route construction.
In your case it works partially because the uid is probably calculated once.
If you check your uid after more than one message, you should notice that it probably does never change.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `toD()` if you want a dynamic destination. The expression in the parenthesis is interpreted with `simple()` language. No `simple()` needed.

```
toD("file:/tmp?fileName=file-${exchangeProperty.uid}.xml")
```

But pay attention to not creating too many endpoints.

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/toD-eip.html

Comment: ${property.xxx} is deprecated in 2.x. Use ${exchangeProperty.xxx} which is the correct name for the function.