# Accessing camel properties in DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I have properties defined in camel context xml as follows. These properties will vary for different calls coming from API's exposed.

```
<util:properties id="abc-properties">
     <prop key="serviceId"></prop>
     <prop key="name"></prop>
 </util:properties>
<propertyPlaceholder location="ref:abc-properties" id="properties" />
```

In my Java DSL I am trying to access these properties as follows in 'from' and in 'to'

```
from(Identifier + ":" + abcName + "://{{serviceId}}")
to(Identifier + ":" + abcName + "://{{serviceId}}")
```

When I my DSL routes are formed, I see that for 'to' I don't get updated value of serviceId. Value which had come first time continues to appear for all subsequent calls. for 'from' I always get updated value for serviceId.

By referring post [Use Exchange Property in Camel DSL "to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222720/use-exchange-property-in-camel-dsl-to) , I tried using recipientList but that too dosen't seems to be working.

Do I need to use any other syntax to access property in 'to' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```java
from(
    Identifier + ":" + abcName + "://{{serviceId}}"
).recipientList(
    simple(Identifier + ":" + abcName + "://${properties:serviceId}")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Cslysy. Just one correction  here, I am not calling 'to' after 'from'. I have it separately in my Routebuilder class for different purpose.  I am exposing endpoints using  definition 
Identifier + ":" + abcName + "://{{serviceId}}"
I tried using recipientList but it dint generate my endpoint so was looking out for syntax which i can mention in 'to' to get proper value of property.

Comment: Worked afetr some other tweaks along with using recipientList.